# An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/name/package.json: Unexpected token \\ in JSON at position 1" not a similar question

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, yarnpkg

So I was running yarn command and got this error no matter what project i was in.

> error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/name/package.json:
> Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1".
>
> > Trace:    SyntaxError: /Users/name/package.json: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
> > at JSON.parse ()
> > at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:1625:59
> > at Generator.next ()
> > at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
> > at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:321:13

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
module.exports =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/
```

Package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "vue-cli-sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "description": "Sample project generated using Vue-CLI",
  "author": "Irfan Maulana <github.com/mazipan>",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service serve --host localhost",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "npm run serve",
    "dist": "npm run dist",
    "test:unit": "npm run test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.16.0",
    "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
    "parse-json": "^2.2.0",
    "register-service-worker": "1.6.2",
    "vue": "2.6.10",
    "vue-introjs": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-router": "3.0.7",
    "vuex": "3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.9.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "eslint": "6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "5.2.3",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "2.0.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "2.0.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.1",
    "less": "3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "5.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "9.2.0",
    "vue-jest": "3.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.7.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.7.2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mazipan/vue-cli-sample/issues"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": [
      "vue-cli-service lint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/mazipan/vue-cli-sample.git"
  }
}
```

My yarn version v1.22.5
I have both node version 12 and 15 it uses 15 as default

Comment: so, what does `package.json` look like?

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do, and show us the `package.json`

Comment: So i have updated the post.

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean the package /Users/name/package.json? Cause it consists of this line only:  {\n  "name": "test",\n}\n

Comment: yep ... well, there's the issue ... \ is not a valid there

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was with my /Users/name/package.json.
To solve it you need to erase your node modules and package.json. Then you need to do npm install, npm install yarn. For my case i did this in /Users/[name]/ folder.

Comment: So, what you're saying is, you need valid JSON in the file `package.json`